# How to intercept the various button press of a mouse using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mouse, mouseevent

The web application I work on was designed and developed during the period where there existed only 2-button mice. Now that we have more than 3-button mice available in the market, all those extra buttons are causing havoc while using our application.

My intention is to allow the user to press only the left mouse button and disable all other buttons on his mice. Since, I do not have access to the user's system, I have to achieve this somehow through the browser itself (probably by using JavaScript).

How can I go about solving this problem? Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*W3C event model* is kind enough to pass mouse information through the `event object`. That means you can actually read **which** mouse button was clicked. Example

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    console.log('mouse button clicked: ', event.which);
}, false);
```

With that information its fairly trivial to only allow *left-clicks*, which are represented by the value `1`.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    if( event.which === 1 ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Hello @jAndy. Thanks for the response. I have a mouse with 5 buttons on it. This code does detect the left, middle and right click of the mouse buttons, but does not detect the click of the buttons available on the (left/right) sides of the mouse. The web console does not display anything when I use those buttons on the side of the mouse. So it seems those events aren't being detected. Or could it be some other reason?

Comment: @Rishabh afaik browsers only support 3-button mouses by default. Any other "click" needs to be available through a special driver or software from that mouse manufacturer. But even then, I don't think those "additional" mouse buttons would get recognized by a browser. But you can try it by attaching a click handler on the document and log the event object to your console, when clicking those buttons. Anyway, if you only want to allow left-clicks, you don't have to care about other clicks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser and document mode.

This is how we tweaked prototype.js buttonmaps to work on all browsers. Including IE10 in docmode < 9.

```
function _isButtonForDOMEvents(event, code) {
        return event.which ? (event.which === code + 1) : (event.button === code);
    }

    //var legacyButtonMap = { 0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2 };
    function _isButtonForLegacyEvents(event, code) {
        switch (code) { //Fix where IE10 in DocMode lt9 caused isLeftClick to fail
            case 0: return event.button == 0 || event.button == 1;
            case 1: return event.button == 4;
            case 2: return event.button == 2;
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    function _isButtonForWebKit(event, code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 0: return event.which == 1 && !event.metaKey;
            case 1: return event.which == 2 || (event.which == 1 && event.metaKey);
            case 2: return event.which == 3;
            default: return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is the closest you will get to disabling the buttons

```
document.addEventListener('click', function( e ){
    if(e.which === 2 || e.which === 3) { // 2 = middle scroll button ||  3 = right click
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

> Instead of click if it doesn't work you can try 'keydown' or 'keyup'